# How do I grab the values of a Javascript variable using server side control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use this code below to calculate distance between two locations.

It works in terms of displaying the correct results.

The results are the FROM location, the TO location, and total miles.

What I am having problem with is how the values of

```
 `<asp:Label ID="results" runat="server"></asp:Label>`
```

on one multiview control called vwPersonalData can be previewed on the multiview control called vwPreviewData at the click of the **Next** button.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var geocoder, location1, location2, gDir;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        gDir = new GDirections();
        GEvent.addListener(gDir, "load", function () {
            var drivingDistanceMiles = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1609.344;
            var drivingDistanceKilometers = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;

            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '<strong>From: </strong>' + location1.address + '<br /><strong>To: </strong>' + location2.address + '<br /><strong>Driving Distance: </strong>' + drivingDistanceMiles.toFixed(2) + ' miles ';
        });
    }

    function showLocation() {
        geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address1.value, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
                alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the first address");
            }
            else {
                location1 = { lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address };
                geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address2.value, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
                        alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the second address");
                    }
                    else {
                        location2 = { lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address };
                        gDir.load('from: ' + location1.address + ' to: ' + location2.address);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

//HTML

```
 <asp:MultiView ID="myMultiView" ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="vwPersonalData" runat="server">
            <p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="address1" runat="server" Text="Orlando, FL" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="address2" runat="server" Text="Birmingham, AL" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            </p>
             <asp:Label ID="results" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
        </asp:View>
      <asp:View ID="vwPreviewData" runat="server">
             <asp:Label ID="lblPreviewresults" runat="server"></asp:Label>
       </asp:view>
    </asp:MultiView>
 <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next &gt;" OnClientClick="showLocation(); return false;" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />
```

Comment: just put your variable value into hidden field and then retrieve hidden field value in server side....@T

Comment: `Label` is not an input element, so value what you set to `Label` from client side may not reflect on server side.